# Opera select background image not display

Tags: css, select, xhtml, background-image, opera

CSS

```
noindex:-o-prefocus, .city-list select {
    height:20px;
    margin:3px 0 0;
    background-image: url("back.png");
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-style:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="city-list">
    <select name="">
      <option></option>
    </select>

</div>
```

I use doctype and background: rgba(0,0,0,0) but don't work for opera 12.14. How can I fix this?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932010/select-list-styled-with-image-overlay-not-working-in-opera

Answer (score 2):

do you try  `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);` ?